# Why is there a plot.lm help page, whilst the function plot.lm does not exist

Tags: r

I was trying to figure out what kind of smoothed line was used in the residuals vs fitted plot of the default r `plot` for an `lm` object, so I checked the help page by typing `?plot.lm`, since to my understanding the `<function>.<type>` is how these kind of default behaviors for different object types are defined.

As expected there was a help page but it didn't specifically mention the smoothed line in the residuals vs fitted plot, so I wanted to check the base code, normally for a function you can get the code by typing it in the console without brackets. but typing `plot.lm` into the console gave the error `object 'plot.lm' not found`. Since the help page says it's in the `stats` package I also tried `stats::plot.lm`, but to no effect. I tried `plot` and some `plot.<something>` variants like `plot.default` and they did exist and gave code.

Why is there a help page for `plot.lm` whilst there doesn't seem to be a function called `plot.lm` and where is the plotting behavior for `lm` objects defined if not in `plot.lm`?

I expect it has something to do with the difference between S3 and S4 methods, but I don't know enough about that side of R to figure it out.

Comment: It's an S3 method that isn't exported. Type `stats:::plot.lm` at the console.

Comment: If you run `methods("plot")` you'll see `plot.lm` listed with an `*` which means it's a hidden/un-exported function -- but it does exist. It's pretty common to hide custom methods for generic functions. Also `getAnywhere(plot.lm)` would have found it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question recently myself when writing a function to plot the default plot.lm() plots with ggplot2 instead. From what I can tell from the source code, plot.lm() calls panel.smooth(), which in turn calls stats::lowess(), the source code of which is:

```
function (x, y = NULL, f = 2/3, iter = 3L, delta = 0.01 * diff(range(x))) 
{
    xy <- xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE)
    o <- order(xy$x)
    x <- as.double(xy$x[o])
    list(x = x, y = .Call(C_lowess, x, as.double(xy$y[o]), f, 
        iter, delta))
}
```

So we can see that it calls C_lowess(). Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to access the source code for this function in R; I assume it's written in either C/C++. However, the original implementation seems to come from [this paper](http://home.eng.iastate.edu/~shermanp/STAT447/Lectures/Cleveland%20paper.pdf) by well-known statistician William Cleveland. If anyone knows how this particular function is implemented in R I personally would love to know!